# Mapping an object to another complex object

Tags: c#, automapper

I have the following Request and Response structure:

```
public class Action
{
    public class Create
    {
        public class Request
        {
            public string operationdate { get; set; }
            public string action { get; set; }
            public string identificationaccount { get; set; }
            public string observation { get; set; }
            private ErrorModel.Error errorrow = new ErrorModel.Error();
            public ErrorModel.Error ErrorRow { get { return errorrow; } set { errorrow = value; } }
        }
        public class Response : Request
        {
            public Int32 version { get; set; }
            public string groupcode { get; set; }
            public bool active { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

and I want to map to the following DTO structure:

```
public class GroupDTO
{
    public Int64 idGroup { get; set; }
    public string GroupCode { get; set; }
    public string GroupDate { get; set; }
    public string Obs01 { get; set; }
    public string Obs02 { get; set; }
    public string Obs03 { get; set; }
    public string Obs04 { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
    private List<ActionModelDTO> _Actions = new List<ActionModelDTO>();
    public List<ActionModelDTO> Actions { get { return _Actions; } set { _Actions = value; } }
}

public class ActionModelDTO
{
    public Int64 idAction { get; set; }
    public string ActionDate { get; set; }
    public Int32 Version { get; set; }
    public Int32 idGroup { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
    private ActionDetailModelDTO _ActionDetailModel = new ActionDetailModelDTO();
    public ActionDetailModelDTO ActionDetailModel { get { return _ActionDetailModel; } set { _ActionDetailModel = value; } }
    private ActionUserDetailModelDTO _ActionUserDetailModel = new ActionUserDetailModelDTO();
    public ActionUserDetailModelDTO ActionUserDetailModel { get { return _ActionUserDetailModel; } set { _ActionUserDetailModel = value; } }
}

public class ActionDetailModelDTO
{
    public Int64 idActionDetailModel { get; set; }
    public Int32 idActionType { get; set; }
    public string ActionType { get; set; }
}

public class ActionUserDetailModelDTO
{
    public Int64 idActionUserDetailModel { get; set; }
    public string UserAccount { get; set; }
    public string UserObservation { get; set; }
    public string IdentificationNumber { get; set; }
}
```

The mapping would be the following:

1. `Action.Create.Request.operationdate` => `ActionModelDTO.ActionDate`
2. `Action.Create.Request.action` => `ActionDetailModelDTO.ActionType`
3. `Action.Create.Request.identificationaccount` => `ActionUserDetailModelDTO.UserAccount`
4. `Action.Create.Request.observation` => `ActionUserDetailModelDTO.UserObservation`

The object to which you would have to map is GroupDTO ... it is the first time I use Automapper, and it returns the following error:

> Unmapped members were found. Review the types and members below. Add a
>   custom mapping expression, ignore, add a custom resolver, or modify
>   the source/destination type For no matching constructor, add a no-arg
>   ctor, add optional arguments, or map all of the constructor parameters

The fields that do not appear in the mapping that I specified are completed after the object persists in DB.

Regards!

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] which can be compiled and tested by others. Specially, add your mapping configuration to your question and show how you map the properties from one type to the other type.

Comment: http://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Configuration-validation.html